# Show that $\sqrt{x+f(x)}-\sqrt x-\frac12 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}\rightarrow-\frac{l^2}8$ as $x\rightarrow \infty.$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions

> Let $f:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a function such that $\frac{f(x)}{x^{3/4}}\rightarrow l$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$. Show that $\sqrt{x+f(x)}-\sqrt x-\frac12 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}\rightarrow-\frac{l^2}8$ as $x\rightarrow \infty.$

I can't really see where to even begin, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: multiply $\sqrt{x+f(x)} - \sqrt{x}$ by its conjugate, and then add this result to $-\frac{f(x)}{2 \sqrt{x}}$ simplifying all this stuff. Notice that $f(x)/x \to 0$.

Answer (score 2):

Rationalize denominator in order to get
$$L_x=\sqrt{x+f(x)}-\sqrt x-\frac12 \frac{f(x)}{\sqrt x}=-\frac{f^2(x)}{2x^{3/2}}\frac{1}{(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{f(x)}{x}})^2}.$$
Then,
$$\lim_{x\to\infty}L_x=-\frac{1}{2}l^2\frac{1}{2^2}=-\frac{l^2}{8}$$